# flexslider-rtl not shown on chrome after chrome last update

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, flexslider

Flexslider on rtl website not shown after last update to chrome, I've to change the css `direction: rtl` to ltr then return it rtl again to work!
Even on their website the example not show. [example link](http://rtl-this.com/sites/default/files/demos/FlexSlider/demo/basic-rtl.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem today and had to find a quick fix, a better fix will probably come along later...

I added a this style:

```
.flexslider-fix-rtl{
    width: 100% !important;
    transform: initial !important;
}
```

Then just before the flexslider setup call i added the class:

```
jQuery('.slides').addClass('flexslider-fix-rtl');
```

Then inside the flexslider call remove the class via the start parameter:

```
start: function() {
jQuery('.slides').removeClass('flexslider-fix-rtl');
}
```

Good luck.